# Copying big endian float data directly into a vector<float> and byte swapping in place. Is it safe?

Tags: c++, floating-point, endianness

I'd like to be able to copy big endian `float` arrays directly from an unaligned network buffer into a `std::vector<float>` and perform the byte swapping back to host order "in place", without involving an intermediate `std::vector<uint32_t>`. Is this even safe? I'm worried that the big endian float data may accidentally be interpreted as NaNs and trigger unexpected behavior. Is this a valid concern?

For the purposes of this question, assume that the host machine receiving the data is little endian.

Here's some code that demonstrates what I'm trying to do:

```cpp
std::vector<float> source{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};
std::size_t number_count = source.size();

// Simulate big-endian float values being received from network and stored
// in byte buffer. A temporary uint32_t vector is used to transform the
// source data to network byte order (big endian) before being copied
// to a byte buffer.
std::vector<uint32_t> temp(number_count, 0);
std::size_t byte_length = number_count * sizeof(float);
std::memcpy(temp.data(), source.data(), byte_length);
for (uint32_t& datum: temp)
    datum = ::htonl(datum);
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(byte_length, 0);
std::memcpy(buffer.data(), temp.data(), byte_length);
// buffer now contains the big endian float data, and is not aligned at word boundaries

// Copy the received network buffer data directly into the destination float vector
std::vector<float> numbers(number_count, 0.0f);
std::memcpy(numbers.data(), buffer.data(), byte_length); // IS THIS SAFE??

// Perform the byte swap back to host order (little endian) in place,
// to avoid needing to allocate an intermediate uint32_t vector.
auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(numbers.data());
for (size_t i=0; i<number_count; ++i)
{
    // IS THIS SAFE??
    uint32_t datum;
    std::memcpy(&datum, ptr, sizeof(datum));
    *datum = ::ntohl(*datum);
    std::memcpy(ptr, &datum, sizeof(datum));
    ptr += sizeof(datum);
}

assert(numbers == source);
```

Note the two "IS THIS SAFE??" comments above.

**Motivation**: I'm writing a CBOR serialization library with support for [typed arrays](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-cbor-array-tags-00). CBOR allows typed arrays to be transmitted as either big endian or little endian.

**EDIT**: Replaced illegal `reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>` type punning in endian swap loop with `memcpy`.

Comment: I just realized that in the case of a little endian float array being received over the wire, I may still have to handle signalling NaNs before they are copied to the destination float vector. An application using my library may want to enable signalling NaN exceptions for it's own floating-point computations, but not have them triggered when signalling NaNs are received over the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit:

Regarding the `auto datum = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(numbers.data());`: This is not allowed in C++, one can only safely type-pun to `uint8_t` (only if CHAR_BIT == 8, more precisely this type-punning exception only holds for the `char` types)

Old answer:
Below is for the question before the edit (the one with `bit_cast`).

This is safe, provided `sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t)`

Dont worry about signaling NaNs. The exceptions are usually disabled, and even if they are enabled, they are only happening when a signaling NaN is generated. The move instructions do not generate exceptions.

Accessing the vector elements via `data()` pointer is supported (for both reading and writing). `vector` is guarantueed to have a contiguous storage.

But why aren't you doing all in only a single loop without the temp buffers?

Just have the float vector (input or output) and the data buffer (uint8_t vector).
For sending just iterate over the float input vector, for each element perform the byte swapping and write the 4 bytes to the data buffer. One at a time. Then you do not need any intermediate buffers. It will probably not be slower. For receiving do the reverse.

Use `std::bit_cast` for conversion of float from/to `std::array<uint8_t,4>`. This would be the "correct" way in C++20 (you cant use C arrays directly with bit_cast).
With this approach you do not need to invoke `ntohl`, just copy the bytes in correct order from/to buffer.

Comment: I was already thinking along these same lines (single loop), and I'm glad to see someone else confirm it. Thanks!

I admit the signalling NaN behavior is a bit of a mystery to me (never needed it before), and I need to spend time studying how it works.

Comment: Since signaling NaNs are so rarely used (I have never seen it), I would not be surprised when different implementations actually show different behavior... (intentional or not)

Comment: I already have a generic hand-written endian swap function that optimizes to a single assembly instruction. I used `ntohl` in my question to keep it simple since most would already be familiar with it.

Comment: I see, you could still `bit_cast` to `uint32_t` use your swap, cast address of uint to `uint8_t *` and then `memcpy` to destination.

Comment: Don't you mean `memcpy` to `uint32_t`, swap, `bit_cast` to `float` and append to the destination `vector<float>`?

Comment: yes, sorry, I was thinking of the sending process not receive. But receive is just as you have written

Answer (score 2):

Based on Andreas' suggestion of a single loop, the copy & swap code would look something like this (not tested):

```cpp
std::vector<float> numbers(number_count, 0.0f); // Destination
auto ptr = buffer.data();
for (auto& number: numbers)
{
    uint32_t datum;
    std::memcpy(&datum, ptr, sizeof(datum));
    number = std::bit_cast<float>(endian_swap(datum));
    ptr += sizeof(datum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ntohl() probably will interpret data as integers (Network TO Host Long). But to be sure I recommend byte-swapping first using only integer operations, then coping the buffer to a float vector.

Comment: Do you mean byte-swapping on the unaligned buffer? Byte-swapping on the unaligned buffer is likely not going to be as efficient as byte swapping on an aligned `vector<uint32_t>` or `vector<float>`. The way CBOR is designed, it's impossible to guarantee that the inbound typed array is aligned at word boundaries.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't paid attention the first buffer was unaligned. You could do in the aligned buffer (numbers.data()) casting its pointer to uint32_t* . So you program will use only integer instruction during swapping.

Comment: That's what I did in my original question (before the edit), but it's not permitted in standard C++ under strict aliasing rules. I'm going with Andreas' suggestion of a single loop where I `memcpy` the next 4 bytes from the unaligned buffer to a `uint32_t`, swap the `uint32_t`, then append the `bit_cast<float>` result to the destination vector.